# hibernate + jtable + and autorefresh

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, jtable, refresh

I hava application which I'm using to present data from DB. I'm using hibernate which is great. All I need is to build mechanism to auto refresh JTable.

Right now I'm rebuilding table every minute. I would like to refresh cells without this process. I figure out the best way to do it is to implement table model.

In one of table cells I have my Object ( ex. User ) the problem is that when I'm caling SQL 
query I'm getting new object list and I'm getting error from JTable.

I know that I can update objects one by obe but this is not optimal.

Any help, tutorial etc.

Answer (score 1):

Execute your query periodically in your implementation of `doInBackground()` in a subclass of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). The `process()` method allows the model to be updated on the EDT. Examples may be found in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata).